# Binary Image Dataframe to Euclidean coordinates

Tags: python, image, pandas

I am looking to take a dataframe of an image that is binary boolean of False/True's and transform it into an array of coordinates where the data frame is true.

For example, if index[4] and column[8] is true, it would add 4,8 to the array.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [70]: df
Out[70]:
       a      b      c
0   True  False   True
1   True   True  False
2  False   True   True
3  False   True   True
4   True  False  False
5  False   True  False
6   True  False  False
7  False   True  False
8  False  False   True
9   True  False   True

In [71]: np.dstack(np.nonzero(df.values))[0]
Out[71]:
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 1],
       [6, 0],
       [7, 1],
       [8, 2],
       [9, 0],
       [9, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

or:

```
In [76]: np.stack(np.nonzero(df.values)).T
Out[76]:
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 1],
       [6, 0],
       [7, 1],
       [8, 2],
       [9, 0],
       [9, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

**Setup:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], (10, 3)), columns=list('abc'))
```

Answer (score 1):

***setup***

using @MaxU's example dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': [True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, True],
        'b': [False, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, False],
        'c': [True, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True]})
```

---

I'm guessing you want coordinates in terms of the dataframe's `index` and 'columns`

***Option 1***
`stack` + `mask`

```
s = df.stack()
s[s].index.values

array([(0, 'a'), (0, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'),
       (3, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'a'), (5, 'b'), (6, 'a'), (7, 'b'),
       (8, 'c'), (9, 'a'), (9, 'c')], dtype=object)
```

***Option 2***
Just positions with `np.where`

```
np.stack(np.where(df.values)).reshape(-1, 2)

array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9],
       [9, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 2]])
```

​***Option 3***
Back to `index` and `columns` using `np.where`

```
r, c = np.where(df.values)
list(zip(df.index[r], df.columns[c]))

[(0, 'a'),
 (0, 'c'),
 (1, 'a'),
 (1, 'b'),
 (2, 'b'),
 (2, 'c'),
 (3, 'b'),
 (3, 'c'),
 (4, 'a'),
 (5, 'b'),
 (6, 'a'),
 (7, 'b'),
 (8, 'c'),
 (9, 'a'),
 (9, 'c')]
```